# how to solve $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Knowing that $p$ is prime and if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$; how do I solve $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{13}$?

Comment: Set $p=13$ in $\left(\frac{p-1}2\right)!$

Comment: The problem tells you that $6!$ is one of the two solutions. You may want to calculate the remainder when $6!$ is divided by $13$ for a nicer-looking answer. The other answer will be easy to write down.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but when I tried to substitute I get 721 which is not   divisible by 13. How to find the second solution ?

Comment: Can anybody explain how to prove that (((p-1)/2)! )^2 is congruent to -1 mod p when p congruent to 1 mod 4? @labbhattacharjee

Comment: How did you get $721$ from André’s suggestion? You know that $720$ is one solution to your congruence; he’s suggesting that you reduce it mod $13$ to get a nicer form for it. Once you’ve done that, getting the other solution, $-x$, will be easy.

Comment: In various ways, for example calculation, you can show that $6!\equiv 5\pmod{13}$. Now recall that if $x=a$ is a solution of $x^2\equiv b\pmod{m}$, then $x=-a$ is also a solution. That gives $-5$, which is congruent to $8$, if you prefer to avoid negatives.

Comment: in x^2 is congruent to -1 mod 13 if x is 6! then we must get that 6!+1 must be divided by 13 which is not possible.@BrianM.Scott

Comment: In a comment, you ask also for a proof of the general result you have been asked to use. Presumably that is in your text. It has also been asked and answered several times on MSE.

Comment: $4!\equiv 24\equiv -2$; so $5!\equiv -10\equiv 3$; so $6!\equiv 18\equiv 5$.

Comment: It is $(6!)^2+1$ that must be divisible by 13.

Comment: The stuff about factorials shows there are solutions, but to actually find them why not
just compute $1^2, 2^2, 3^2, \ldots, 6^2 \mod 13$?

Comment: @alifeliachi In checking that $x^2\equiv-1\pmod{13}$ for $x=6!$, you forgot to take the square of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$p-r\equiv-r\pmod p$$

putting $r=1,2,\cdots,\frac{p-1}2$ and multiplying we get
  $$\prod_{\frac{p+1}2\le r\le p-1 }r\equiv(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2} \prod_{1\le s\le \frac{p-1}2 }s$$

$$\prod_{\frac{p+1}2\le r\le p-1 }r\equiv\prod_{1\le s\le \frac{p-1}2 }s\text{ as } \frac{p-1}2 \text{ is even}$$

Multiplying by $\displaystyle \prod_{1\le s\le \frac{p-1}2 }s\text{ as } \frac{p-1}2, $ we get 
$$\left(\prod_{1\le s\le \frac{p-1}2 }s\right)^2\equiv \prod_{1\le r\le p-1 }r=(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p$$ using Wilson's Theorem

But $\displaystyle \prod_{1\le s\le \frac{p-1}2 }s=\left(\frac{p-1}2\right)!$